# What is the difference between the random.choices() and random.sample() functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have the following list: `list = [1,1,2,2]`.

After applying the `sample` method (`rd.sample(list, 3)`) the, output is `[1, 1, 2]`.

After applying the `choices` method (`rd.choices(list, 3)`), the output is: `[2, 1, 2]`.

What is the difference between these two methods? When should one be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The fundamental difference is that [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) will (eventually) draw elements at the same position (always sample from the entire sequence, so, once drawn, the elements are replaced - *with replacement*), while [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) will not (once elements are picked, they are removed from the population to sample, so, once drawn the elements are not replaced - *without replacement*).

Note that here [*replaced*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/replace) (*replacement*) should be understood as *placed back* (*placement back*) and not as a synonym of *substituted* (and *substitution*).

To better understand it, let's consider the following example:

```
import random


random.seed(0)


ll = list(range(10))

print(random.sample(ll, 10))
# [6, 9, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 8, 7]

print(random.choices(ll, k=10))
# [5, 9, 5, 2, 7, 6, 2, 9, 9, 8]
```

As you can see, `random.sample()` does not produce repeating elements, while `random.choices()` does.

---

In your example, both methods have results with repeating values because you have repeating values in the original sequence, but, in the case of `random.sample()` those  repeating values must come from different positions of the original input.

---

Eventually, you cannot `sample()` more than the size of the input sequence, while this is not an issue with `choices()`:

```
# print(random.sample(ll, 20))
# ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative


print(random.choices(ll, k=20))
# [9, 3, 7, 8, 6, 4, 1, 4, 6, 9, 9, 4, 8, 2, 8, 5, 0, 7, 3, 8]
```

A more generic and theoretical discussion of the sampling process can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)).

Comment: What about random.choice()?  without the last 's'.

Comment: @skan That would be very similar to [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) except that with [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) only a single element is drawn **with replacement**. This is not specified in the documentation because it is implicit that unless otherwise stated or obvious from context, library functions are *stateless*, and a stateless function drawing only one element can only be with replacement.

Answer (score 6):

The basic difference is this:

- Use the [`random.sample`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-random-sample-function/) function when you want to choose multiple random items from a list without including the duplicates.
- Use [`random.choices`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choices.asp) function when you want to choose multiple items out of a list including repeated.

Here are two examples to demonstrate the difference:

```
import random

alpha_list=['Batman', 'Flash', 'Wonder Woman','Cyborg', 'Superman']

choices=random.choices(alpha_list,k=7)
print(choices)

sample= random.sample(alpha_list,k=3)
print(sample)

Output: ['Cyborg', 'Cyborg', 'Wonder Woman', 'Flash', 'Wonder Woman', 'Flash', 'Batman']
['Superman', 'Flash', 'Batman']
```

As from the above examples you can see that, **in random.choices() you can pass 'k' to be greater than length of your sequence, as random.choices() allow for duplicates**.

Whereas, if you were to pass a value of 'k' greater than length of sequence in random.sample() you'll get an error:

> Sample larger than population or is negative.

Now, coming to use cases:

- `random.choices(sequence, weights=None, cum_weights=None, k=1)`: you would like to use this **when you can afford to have duplicates in your sampling**. This is the very reason why we can give a value of `k` > `len(dataset)`.
- `random.sample(sequence, k)`: you would like to use this **when you can't afford to have duplicates while sampling your data**.

For further reading:

- [`random.choices`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choices.asp)
- [`random.sample`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-random-sample-function/)